# Extracting coordinates of 50m squares from shapefile in R

Tags: r, shapefile

I'm trying to extract the coordinates of 50m squares and the flooding factor associated with that square, from data provided by the Environment agency, here (https://data.gov.uk/dataset/risk-of-flooding-from-rivers-and-sea1). I've downloaded the shapefile format, when you click through from that page to this one (http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/catalogue/#/8d57464f-d465-11e4-8790-f0def148f590).

The data claims to show the flooding factor for each 50m square. I'm completely new to Shapefiles and also new to R. From what I've read I expect the 50m squares to be represented by 'Polygons' and have viewed the Polygons using

```
polys <- slot(data,"polygons")
```

and then printing the coordinates of a few of them using

```
for (i in 1:length(polys)) { 
    print(paste("Polygon #",i)) 
    print(slot(slot(polys[[i]],"Polygons")[[1]],"coords"  )) 
    }
```

I'm confused by the output as I assumed a square would be specified by four points, however, the number of (pairs of) coordinates specifying the polygons varies greatly.

Is this assumption correct? Or does the data not consist of 50m squares as it claims?

If they are indeed 50m squares, is there an easy way to extract the coordinates of the centre of the polygons and their IDs?